# Collider is not following character animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a combat animation in my game and I want my hitbox to follow the animation. I have tried using the record feature, but it has not been working. Is there any other ways I can have my problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Colliders get animated with the animation itself and moves accordingly. Make sure that the object you are animating has a collider on itself not on its parent.

Comment: I am sure my colliders are on my object and when I use the animation it doesn't move the enemy. I am using a rigid body system.

Comment: Animators do nothing when there is a active rigid body already doing physics calculation. One workaround is to create a empty parent and move object to be animated as a child of that parent , apply rigid body and physics calculations on parent instead and remove rigid body from child such that only animator is present on it . I hope it helps.

Comment: This has helped but for some reason only one of my animations hitboxes work while the other one doesn't.

Comment: Actually my other animation does work now sorry.

Comment: Please upvoate my answer if it helped @pokefalls

Comment: I need 15 reputation to cast a vote